# Output Buffering php producing nothing - why isn't this working?

Tags: php, xml, parameters, output, output-buffering

In a Joomla template file (index.php) I am trying to get 2 parameters which are set in the admin panel (then wrapped in some css formatting) to create some basic css for google fonts and then save them to a separate css file. Maybe my thoughts on this are all wrong, but here is what I am TRYING to do but needless to say it is producing nothing...

```
    <?php
      ob_start();
     ?>

        <?php echo $this->params->get('googleFont1types');?> {
        font-family: '<?php echo str_replace('+', ' ', $this->params->get('googleFont1'));?>', sans-serif;
        }
        <?php echo $this->params->get('googleFont2types');?> {
            font-family: '<?php echo str_replace('+', ' ', $this->params->get('googleFont2'));?>', serif;
        }"

     <?php
     $googlefontcss = ob_get_contents();
     ob_end_clean();
    file_put_contents('googlefonts.css', $googlefontcss);
     ?>
```

Or do you know of a better way of doing this? I can easily write the styles inline as css like the following (tested and working) - but I dont want inline css ideally. I'd really like to just take this chunk of css and write it to a text file.

```
  <?php
// Use of Google Font
if ($this->params->get('googleFont'))
{
?>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo $this->params->get('googleFont1');?>|<?php echo $this->params->get('googleFont2');?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <style type="text/css">
    <?php echo $this->params->get('googleFont1types');?> {
      font-family: '<?php echo str_replace('+', ' ', $this->params->get('googleFont1'));?>', sans-serif;
    }
    <?php echo $this->params->get('googleFont2types');?> {
        font-family: '<?php echo str_replace('+', ' ', $this->params->get('googleFont2'));?>', serif;
    }
  </style>   

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What is "produces nothing?" Is your googlefonts.css file writeable? What do you get when you var_dump($googlefontcss)?

Comment: there is no googlefonts.ss I thought it would be created by default? Vardump gives this string(174) "         
          h2, h3 {
          font-family: 'Bebas', sans-serif;
          }
          p {
           font-family: 'bitter', serif;
          }"
           
         "

Comment: Which  guess means that I have a permissions issue and not a code one - shouldnt file_put_contents create a file even if it doesnt exist?

Comment: Yes, it's created if it doesn't exist. Check your directory permissions and see if it's writeable, because it looks like output buffering is producing something :)

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions problem - it is fixed now. Thanks for your input Tim